# Add new character to div one at a time, instead of in bunches with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I decided to play around with `Javascript` again after some years. Is it possible to add a character say `"X"` to a `div` one at a time? The behavior the `DOM` seems to be displaying is to wait and add them in bunches. The page is just blank and "spins", and then bam, everything shows up at once. The behavior I'm shooting for is for the `"X's"` to show up one at a time with a `2` seconds delay.

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script>

function wait(ms) {
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;

    do {
        d2 = new Date();
    }
    while (d2 - d < ms);
}

function runTest() {
    var cnt = 0;

    while (cnt < 50) {
        var x = document.getElementById("here");
        x.innerHTML += "X + ";
        wait(2000);
        cnt++;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: How is the `wait()` method implemented? What you want to do is better suited for use `setInterval()`.

Comment: The `wait` function that "works properly" most certainly *doesn't* work properly because it can't work properly in JavaScript, regardless of how it's implemented

Comment: The wait is implemented as in the above edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your `wait()` function is doing what you are expecting: It is implemented as a loop taking up as much resources it can for some amount of time. You can check this on the next example, where two logs (one before, and one after `wait()`) are displayed, but only when the `wait()` function stops taking the resources:

```js
function wait(ms)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;

    do {
        d2 = new Date();
    }
    while (d2 - d < ms);
}

console.log("Before wait() is called");
wait(5000);
console.log("After wait() is done");
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

What you want to do is better suited for [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

## Example with `setInterval()`:

```js
var cnt = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("here");
var ival = setInterval(addX, 2000);

function addX()
{
    if (++cnt > 10)
    {
        clearInterval(ival);
        console.log("Finished!");
        return;
    }

    x.innerHTML += "X + ";
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

The [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) is used to cancel the configured repeated action.

Another way to get what you need is to use a [Promise()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in conjuntion with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to implement your `wait()` method, something like this:

## Example with `Promise`:

```js
function wait(ms)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function runTest()
{
    var cnt = 0;

    while (cnt < 10)
    {
       var x = document.getElementById("here");
       x.innerHTML += "X + ";
       await wait(2000);
       cnt++;
    }
}

runTest();
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using setInterval(). Javascript isn't threaded and wait will cause the entire execution to stop each time you hit it. There are very few instances in which you'll ever use wait().  Instead, you'd want to set an interval to run every X number of seconds.

So the following code will set a function to run every 2s, and whenever the count gets to 50, it then sends a message to the dom telling it to no longer run that function.

```
function divBunches() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("here"); 
  var id = setInterval(addDiv, 2000);
  var count = 0;
  function addDiv() {
    if (count == 50) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      elem.innerHTML += "X + ";
    }
    count++;
  }
}
```